# Assigning values to structure members of a structure inside an array

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list, structure

I'm trying to make an Inventory with arrays, structures, and linked list.
i have a function AddNewStock which is part of a bigger code. When called, This gets the values for the category, supplier, and product name. i get a runtime error when i input a category. I've tried everything and I'm still lost. Any input is good

```
struct ProductListTag
{
    string15 Supplier; 
    string15 Product;
    struct ProductListTag *pLink;
};

typedef struct
{
    string15 Category; 
    struct ProductListTag *ProdList;

} StockInfo;

typedef StockInfo Stock[10];`

/*numCat is number of Categories, assume its a 0*/

void AddNewStock(Stock arrStock, int * numCat)
{   
    printf("What is the product category? ");
    fgets(arrStock[*numCat].Category, LEN15 ,stdin);
    printf("\nWho is the Supplier? ");  
    fgets(arrStock[*numCat].ProdList->Supplier,LEN15,stdin);
    printf("%s",arrStock[*numStock].ProdList->Supplier);
    printf("\nWhat is the product? ");
    fgets((arrStock[*numCat].ProdList->Product),LEN15,stdin);         
}
```

Comment: Hello, could you please tell us what this runtime error is that you are getting?

Comment: does `arrStock[*numCat].ProdList`point to something that has been allocated in memory ?

Comment: Does this even compile? typedef StockInfo Stock[10];`

Comment: the code needs to check the returned value from each call to fgets() to assure there was a successful input operation. And to handle any errors that occur.

Comment: We would need to see the code that calls AddNewStock, particularly the variables that are passed in and their declarations. Maybe the definition of string15 too.

Comment: what is 'string15'?  does it define 'char *',  how would it define an array of 15 characters?

Comment: I need an answer to the titled question as well, but the code provided seems to have other unrelated issues. @ProgramAllDay can you clarify on the above comments to get this answered? I'm afraid to make a duplicate thread.